# UFT: how to get only numeric characters in a filed

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How can I use getroproperty and capture all the numeric characters in a field? for example:

address field: 123 test street

Thanks in advance,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex to fetch all the numbers from your string:

```
str="123 test street"

Set reg = New RegExp
reg.Global=True
reg.IgnoreCase=False
reg.Pattern="\d+"
Set mats = reg.Execute(str)
For Each mat In mats
    MsgBox mat.Value             'You can store this required value in a variable and use it further
Next
```

Alternatively, If you are sure that your string format is going to be exactly as the one you shared, you can use the split method and get the 0th item of that array.

```
str="123 test street"
requiredNumbers = split(str," ")(0)
```